# Ionic 3 / AngularFire2 authState not persisting on Android (but works on Web)

Tags: firebase-authentication, ionic3, angularfire2

Hey all so this is kind of driving me crazy.

Here is the code:

```
  constructor(
    platform: Platform,
    statusBar: StatusBar,
    splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    afAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) {
    afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.rootPage = "TabsPage";
        console.log("logging in");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user)); // user
      } else {
        this.rootPage = "LoginPage";
        console.log("logging out");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user)); // null
      }
    });
```

When run on the web I can login to my app and then log out as expected. However on Android (testing via ionic cordova run android) the user subscription is set and then immediately set to null.

Comment: I just realised when I am testing on Android I am using the console log command -c. This means the app runs in live reload mode which might have something to do with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out!

It was the version of firebase that I was using v4.12.1

I changed to version 4.11.0 and the problem stopped occuring.

Comment: There was an issue with 4.12.1 with `indexedDB` persistence. Those were fixed in [4.13.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.13.0). I recommend you continuously update your version to be up to date on the latest bug fixes and security issues.